# nsolid-proxy exits with error when starting nsolid-console

Tags: nsolid

After downloading and installing the runtime, (etcd-)hub and proxy, I started both the hub and the proxy and tested the config using a super simple nodejs webserver and the nsolid-cli:

```
nsolid-cli --socket 40437 info
```

gives me

```
{
   "id": "0f2a54e6dba5dfe3970ff14999aba88518dca924",
   "app": "TESTAPP",
   "tags": [],
   "pid": 1565,
   "nodeEnv": "production",
   "execPath": "/opt/nsolid/bin/nsolid",
   "main": "/home/someuser/testserver.js"
}
```

when firing up the nsolid-console however, nsolid-proxy dies, throwing

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
at Router.proxy (/opt/nsolid-proxy/router.js:59:18)
at emitThree (events.js:97:13)
at Listener.emit (events.js:175:7)
at Concat.callback (/opt/nsolid-proxy/node_modules/nsolid-listener/listener.js:138:32)
at Concat._done (/opt/nsolid-proxy/node_modules/nsolid-listener/concat.js:47:19)
at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
at Concat.emit (events.js:166:7)
at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:468:14)
at endWritable (_stream_writable.js:478:3)
at Concat.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:443:5)
Shutting down hub
```

Here's what nsolid-console outputs while running with NODE_DEBUG=nsolid:

```
NSOLID 6132: registering default commands
NSOLID 6132: nsolid initializing
NSOLID 6132: nsolid initialized on port 45918

> nsolid-console@1.4.4 start /opt/nsolid-console
> NODE_ENV=production node bin/nsolid-console --interval=1000

NSOLID 6143: registering default commands
NSOLID 6143: nsolid initializing
Server running on http://0.0.0.0:3000
NSOLID 6143: nsolid initialized on port 37954
NSOLID 6143: sending http://localhost:9000/info
POLLING ERROR: socket hang up
NSOLID 6143: sending http://localhost:9000/system_info
POLLING ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9000
```

I tried both setting up the proxy to listen on 127.0.0.1:9000 and 0.0.0.0:9000, as well as using localhost et cetera..

**EDIT**

here's the .nsolid-proxyrc from the nsolid-console directory:

```
{
  "registry": "localhost:4001",
  "port": 9000,
  "denied": [],
  "broadcast_approved": [
    "ping",
    "process_stats",
    "system_stats",
    "system_info",
    "info",
    "versions",
    "startup_times"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a problem with your **nsolid-proxy** configuration file, check for `.nsolid-proxyrc` file inside `nsolid-proxy` folder, default config file should look like:

```
{
  "registry": "localhost:4001",
  "port": 9000,
  "denied": [],
  "broadcast_approved": [
    "ping",
    "process_stats",
    "system_stats",
    "system_info",
    "info",
    "versions",
    "startup_times"
  ]
}
```

Check for `denied` property, it should be an array.

Comment: the .nsolid-proxyrc in ../nsolid-proxy has the same contents as the one in ../nsolid-console. The "denied" property is an array. Thanks!

Comment: So, for some reason your `denied` option is undefined, how are you running the proxy and what version are you running?

Comment: well okay, I replaced the .nsolid-proxyrc in the console dir with the one from the proxy dir and everything works just fine.. Thanks a lot, Julian!